# "Service unavailable" with http handler

Tags: iis, httphandler

I am using IIS 6 on 2003. I have created a HTTP handler dll that inherits from IHttpAsyncHandler. The dll builds into the inetpub\www8080root\common\bin directory. It is meant to intercept all requests.

The web site is set to monitor port 8080. I have created a common folder in the www8080root directory and have created a virtual directory in II6 to point to it. I created a web.config file in the common directory

When I access http://localhost:8080/common/index.html all I get is

```
Service Unavailable
```

I am not sure where this message is coming from. 
w3wp.exe does not start and there is nothing in the error log to indicate a problem.

I have run aspnet_regiis -r

I don't think it is occurring within the handler itself and without w3wp.exe I am unable to attach to the process. I have added Debugger.Break() but nothing happens.

I don't want to load IIS 7 as it conflicts with a legacy application.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. The app pool is set to 'Auto' (start with IIS) and reports that it is started, but there is no w3wp process and no errors reported anywhere. Just 'Service Unavailable'. HTTP Error 503: The service is unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for me was that the identity that the worker process was impersonating was not a member of IIS_WPG. A little more detail in the message would have been nice.